# Disaster Recovery - Restoring SQL Server database without MDF

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, database-restore, disaster-recovery

Given the following (hypothetical) scenario, how would one best backup/restore the database.

1. Daily doing full backups @ 12 am.
2. Hourly doing differentials 1 am, 2am etc
3. Transaction log backups on the half hours, 130am, 230am etc
4. I am also storing the active .ldf file on drive X and the .mdf on drive Y.

Also important the master db is on Y.

Lets say hypothetically the Y drive fails **at 245am.**

I have the full, diffs and transaction logs up until 230am. BUT I also have the `.ldf`.

In theory I would have to probably reinstall SQL Server. Then I would want to recover that database up until 245am.

I have heard of doing a tail-log backup on a restore operation BUT I don't have the `.mdf` anymore. So, I would need to create a new database from my full/diff/log backups. After that I'm not sure how to proceed to get that last 15 minutes of transactions.

I hope this is making sense...

Thanks!

Steve.

Comment: this part 2 scenario ,covers your exact case:http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-backing-up-the-tail-of-the-log/

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: This is perfect ! Thanks - i knew there was a way to do this. I know in Oracle its possible with the redo logs thats why I wasnt giving up. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking,how to take TailLog Backup when you don't have access to MDF files..

This works only if your database is not in BulkLoggedRecovery model or your log doesn't have Bulk logged transactions..This has been covered in depth here: [Disaster recovery 101: backing up the tail of the log](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-backing-up-the-tail-of-the-log/)

Here are the steps in order

1. Create a dummy database with same names
2. Delete all files  of this dummy database,by bringing it offline
3. Copy the original database LDF
4. Bring this database online  which will fail..

Now you can take TailLog Backup using below command..

```
BACKUP LOG dummydb 
TO DISK = N'D:\SQLskills\DemoBackups\DBMaint_Log_Tail.bck' WITH INIT, NO_TRUNCATE;
GO
```

Now since you have all the backups,you can restore to point in time of Failure

Comment: Yes - exactly! Thanks this is exactly what I needed.